# undefined local variable or method `acts_as_gmappable' for gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using gmaps4rails gem in my project for showing google maps on the forms but its showing
"undefined local variable or method `acts_as_gmappable' for gmaps4rails"

i am using rails 4.

gem 'gmaps4rails'
rails generate gmaps4rails:install

in model 
acts_as_gmappable

def gmaps4rails_address
      address
end

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

im having the same issue as of 10/23/13

1. issue happens ONLY when deploy to Heroku; this works fine in my local environment
2. Gemfile contains:

...
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'mysql'
gem 'haml'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'json'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
...

1. already tried bundle install / bundle update  & heroku restart
2. trace is as follows:

---> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       undefined method `acts_as_gmappable' for #<Class:0x007fa770b8ba68>
       /tmp/build_94e76989-9e4f-4eef-8e2c-e31cd7d850c9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/g    ems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in`method_missin    g'
       /tmp/build_94e76989-9e4f-4eef-8e2c-e31cd7d850c9/app/models/hay_shipper.rb:    4:in `'

Comment: Try with this rails g gmaps4rails:install if you are using gmaps4rails 1.5.6